# How to add Amazon's X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET:ConfigSet to a my postfix mail server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix, email-server

**Question:** [Amazon shows an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html#send-email-postfix-advanced) on how to add their **X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET:ConfigSet** to a single email. How do I add this to my postfix configuration so it uses it for all outgoing emails?

**Answer from Michael Hampton Below:**

I created a script to run on my servers based on Michael Hampton's answer. Maybe this can help someone.

```
#!/bin/bash

PrivateIP="123.123.123.123"
MyEmailAddress="email@gmail.com"
AmazonConfigSet="data-transporter"

#-- Install postfix-pcre
sudo apt-get install postfix-pcre -y

#-- Create 3 lines that append to your /etc/postfix/main.cf
{ echo ""; echo '#-- Amazon Simple Email Service'; echo "smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set"; } >> /etc/postfix/main.cf

#-- Create file with your configset name
echo "/^From:/ PREPEND X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: ${AmazonConfigSet}" > /etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set

#-- Postmap
postmap -q - pcre:/etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set <ses-configuration-set

#-- Send test email to your email account
echo "Test From $(hostname) and the header should contain ip ${PrivateIP}" | mail -s "Amazon IP Test From $(hostname)" "$MyEmailAddress"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Postfix `header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) (though you will likely want to use the related `smtp_header_checks` so that it applies only to outgoing mail).

For instance, you can add to `main.cf`:

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set
```

Then you create `/etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set` which contains the header checks:

```
/^From:/ PREPEND X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: ConfigSet
```

(where `ConfigSet` is your configuration set name)

(And note that the space is supposed to be there. That the space is missing in Amazon's example is a minor error.)

Reload postfix and Bob's your uncle.

This will cause Postfix to prepend the header before the `From:` header. If your outgoing mails don't have a `From:` header, (though they should!) choose a different one that they will contain, such as `Subject:` or `Content-Type:`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Hats off to you mate.

Answer (score 1):

[Mikes answer](https://serverfault.com/a/925350/536616) above was perfect, putting X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET preamble on every mail we forward through AWS SES from our postfix docker.

However, to help others, I then got this error:

**warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/ses-configuration-set is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre**

resolved with:

`apt-get update -y && apt-get install postfix-pcre -y`

`systemctl reload postfix` (If on a non-container)